# Asus motherboard has no raid post. Is this correct?

Tags: bios, raid, post

I have an ASUS 970 PRO GAMING/AURA motherboard in which I'm trying to set up raid. When i set the sata mode to RAID,  and restart,  there is no separate post for RAID setup,  and the usual AMD hotkeys do not work in the normal post (ctrl f, ctrl i).  Im starting to struggle to find out where i went wrong.  Is there supposed to be no raid screen,  and if not,  how does one set up raid with this motherboard under the bios?

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous The motherboard does not support raid, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This motherboard has no raid capabilities, and the RAID option for SATA drives is there because of a bug in the BIOS.